# How can I apply a negative lookahead to a whole capture group?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given the following regular expression and subject text, why is the negative lookahead only applying to the last character of the named capture group `URL`?

```
// Regex
(?<URL>(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*)(?!'|"|(</a))

// Subject text
<p><a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a> and http://example.com</p>
```

This regex has a negative lookahead `(?!"|(</a))` which is an attempt to not match URLs that are within a `<a>` tag. This is done by checking if the URL is followed by a quote (`'` or `"`) or a closing `</a` tag.

I'm getting the following results

```
http://example.co  
http://example.co  
http://example.com
```

I expected the negative lookahead to apply to the whole capture group, not just it's last char. Is this possible? What am I doing wrong? I expected to match only the last instance of `http://example.com` to be captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when the negative lookahead fails the quantifiers (and anything else that can) will backtrack, till it finds a match.

You can force an expression not to backtrack by using [atomic groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#nonbacktracking_subexpression) `(?>expression)`:

```
(?<URL>(?>(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*))(?!'|"|(</a))
```